# Is it possible to make this code work?

Tags: javascript

Here is what i have so far.  I'm not fantastic with javascript, but oddly enough, i'm the only guy at work that knows enough to get this far.   what we're aiming for is a local html page, that allows people to save their schedules locally to a .txt file.  i'm having an issue getting the file to pull more than one set of radio buttons input.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

pom.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(pom);

pom.click();

document.body.removeChild(pom);
}

function addTextTXT()
{
document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".txt"
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="addtext" onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['m1']
['m2'].value)" />
<P> Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday    
Sunday
<br><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m1" value="m1 3-9" id="Monday1" />
        3-9
        <br><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m1" value="m1 5-9"  />
        5-9
        <br> <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m1" value="m1 off"  /> 
        Off
<br>
<br>Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday    Sunday
<br><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m2" value="m23-9" id="Monday2" />
        3-9
        <br><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m2" value="m25-9"  />
        5-9
        <br> <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m2" value="m2off"  /> 
        Off
<P><input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="ID Number">
<input type="submit" onClick="addTexttxt();" value="Save As TXT">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

currently, i just have the code for the 2 mondays, named m1, and m2, for simplicity's sake.  if there's a better way for me to go about this, i'm all ears.

Comment: Error msgs, or an area that you are having issues with?

Comment: When i run the script, it only returns the value for m1 or m2, but not both.  it's driving me nuts.

Comment: to clarify, i believe i'm having trouble with this line: onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['m1']['m2'].value)

Comment: `I'm not fantastic with javascript` - javascript is easier to read when it's properly indented

Comment: your onsubmit does `download(this['name'].value, this['m1']['m2'].value)` - can you see the problem? should it be `download(this['name'].value, this['m1'].value+this['m2'].value)`

Comment: also `<form name="addtext" onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['m1']
['m2'].value)" />` .. the `/>` is invalid HTML

Comment: also, why is every one of your radio buttons `checked="checked"` ... radio buttons only have one checked in a "group"

Comment: does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb6Lkxpw/) do what you want?

Comment: That got it, thanks.  the resulting txt file doesn't have to be pretty, i've got a bash script parsing it to populate an .xls spreadsheet.  i appreciate the help, and bearing with my sloppy improper code.